# Unable to install qemu on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, command-line, software-installation, system-installation, qemu

I used the following command:

```
sudo apt install libexpect-perl qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
```

But, I received the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 ovmf all 0~20181115.85588389-3+deb10u2
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.210.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/edk2/ovmf_0~20181115.85588389-3+deb10u2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.210.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried running `apt-get update`, but I received the following errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Oh, that was an error. I am using Debian 10!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install qemu qemu-utils qemu-kvm virt-manager \
libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using Debian 10!

Answer (score -1):

nano /etc/apt/sources.list
you fill in the directory

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).